# DJANGO - Using simple history, how can I show both a base model record and a related history group calculation in one query?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-simple-history

I am using the [simple history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) library for my Django project. It's pretty nifty, but I'm having trouble showing aggregated history stats next to a base model object.
Here's what my model looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class RepairForm(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    return_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    status_id = models.ForeignKey(RFormStatus, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...

    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.return_number
```

The [Docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lead me to believe the proper way of accessing historical records is using the history manager. I can get both sets of information I want:

All Forms (base model objects) -

```
RepairForm.objects.all()

User ID |             Return Number            | Status ID
-----------------------------------------------------------
33      | 0a6e6ef0-a444-4b63-bd93-ae55fe8a3cee | 65001
44      | 5f699795-5119-4dcd-8b94-34f7056e732c | 65002
...
```

A history calculation (history object)
In this example I am getting the latest event of each form -

```
RepairForm.history.all()\
            .values('return_number').annotate(latest_event_date=Max('history_date'))\
            .order_by('return_number')

          Return Number              | latest_event_date
-----------------------------------------------------------
0a6e6ef0-a444-4b63-bd93-ae55fe8a3cee | 7/27/2018
5f699795-5119-4dcd-8b94-34f7056e732c | 8/1/2018
...
```

I feel like this should be possible to do in one query though no? One query that outputs something like this:

```
User ID |             Return Number            | Status ID | latest_event_date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
33      | 0a6e6ef0-a444-4b63-bd93-ae55fe8a3cee | 65001     | 7/27/2018
44      | 5f699795-5119-4dcd-8b94-34f7056e732c | 65002     | 8/1/2018
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a property for example "latest_event_date" that calculates the wanted result.then it is always calculated  when you run a query on RepairForm!

```
  @property
  def latest_event_date(self):
      ....
```

Comment: This works! I did:
`@property
    def latest_event_date(self):
        return RepairForm.history.all().filter(return_number=self.return_number).values('return_number').annotate(latest_event_date=Max('history_date')).order_by('return_number')`
And now I can get my data in one object! I am accepting this answer since it is what I asked for but I worry -
Does this mean an additional query is run for EVERY object returned? If I have 20 RepairForms and I call `RepairForms.objects.all()` Does that now mean I am effectively running 20 queries instead of 1?

Comment: yes, since django orm handles that before returning the object it runs another query to get the property you wanted! then it adds it to the wanted query!
but don't worry you can cache the property see [cached property](https://medium.com/@fdemmer/django-cached-property-on-models-f4673de33990)